# codeigniter fluctuating performance/speed

Tags: php, ajax, mongodb, apache, codeigniter

I run into a strange codeigniter 3 problem. I run a website on localhost, and sometime the response time took around 100ms and sometime it took around 1070ms.

The environment: windows 10 wamp, but instead of mysql i use mongodb 3.0.9. Php version: 5.5.12

Announcements:

1.

I have a my_controller file/class and inside it there is a destructor

```
function __destruct(){
    EXIT();
}
```

If i comment out the exit() function, the response time always more than 1 second, but if i leave there the execution time average is around 100ms.

2. I wrote a mongodb library and i load it in the autoload file. I not use this class always, just when i really need. There is one page and after the page is loaded i run an ajax call what use this class and no problem, the response time under 100ms. In the site there is a button what is recall the ajax request but in this case the response time always more than 1 second.

I thought for the first, there is some problem with my class.. but:
i created some tests:
In the top of the index file and define the actual microtime

```
define('CI_BEGIN', microtime(true));
```

In the my_controller class's constructor, i place this:

```
function __construct(){
    var_dump(microtime(true) - CI_BEGIN);
}
```

And the result is always more than 1 second. when i call ajax request, except the first call, then everything is normal and the execution time is under 100ms.

Now I wonder whether this is happened because ci can't destroy my mongodb class?!

I think this is not js/ajax error, because the base ci execution time is the main problem as i explained. The db response and the execution time from my_controller's constructor to response both together always under 70ms.

3. The third strange thing is, the execution time always higher with 1 second, never with 2 or more... It could be a sleep function in ci?

Anybody have idea, where i should to find the error?

**Update:**

**Solved**

I found a solution to a part of the problem, in my mongo library. In this library there was some cross class references. Now the execution time under 100ms.

**BUT**

If i remove the exit function from my_controller's destructor, then the response time increased with 1 second. - this is normal? I don't think so.

Comment: How many libraries are (auto) loaded per request? Is there some third party cURL job or similar? Can you confirm delay with second (fresh) installation?

Comment: The autoload file load only 4 library, and there is no third party.

Comment: Is that new installation (what version?) or existing one?

Comment: You speak about ci version? ci version is 3.0.6

Comment: What happens if you completely remove destructor?

Comment: The same when i comment out the exit() inside it. So in this case every ajax call response time start from 1 second (base ci execution time) + few ms.

Comment: Is there some big data fetch?

Comment: no only 5 document loaded from a small database by id.. But i tested with big data in big db and again only the +1 second is the strange.

Comment: Check server logs.

Comment: i read all log file again but nothing what could be help :(

Comment: Have you checked PHP logs too?

Comment: Of corse, but nothing. Today i going to write more test, maybe i will find something. 1 second on localhost is to much.

Comment: I agree. But also would suggest you to make another CI installation just with isolated code you think is making issue.

Comment: The post have been updated.

Comment: Feel free to write an answer with detailed description of how you solved the problem.

Comment: I will write the answer, but before i must to know the reasons. There is some part, what not clear yet.